# Exibindo registros em tabela criada dinamicamente

Tags: php, mysql

Montei uma tabela dinâmica com dados de uma consulta ao MySQL, quando mostro todos os registros a tabela é exibida corretamente, mas quando solicito somente um registro a tabela não exibe nenhum registro, vejam como está:

```
    mysql_select_db($database_conCurriculo, $conCurriculo);
    $query_rsRegistro = "SELECT nome, email, celular, id_municipio, id_uf, dt_nascimento FROM candidato WHERE id_candidato = 158";
    $rsRegistro = mysql_query($query_rsRegistro, $conCurriculo) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro);
    $totalRows_rsRegistro = mysql_num_rows($rsRegistro);


//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$numCampos = mysql_num_fields($rsRegistro);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$numCampos; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
    $Campos[] = mysql_field_name($rsRegistro,$i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$tabela = '<table border="1"><tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $numCampos; $i++){
    $tabela .= '<th>'.$Campos[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$tabela .= '<tbody>';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rsRegistro)){
    $tabela .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $numCampos; $i++){
        $tabela .= '<td>'.$r[$Campos[$i]].'</td>';
    }
    $tabela .= '</tr>';

    echo $tabela;

}
exit;

//Finalizando a tabela
$tabela .= '</tbody></tabela>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $tabela;
```

Comment: Você tem certeza que está vindo um registro, ou seja que existe esse candidato 158?

Comment: Olá @bigown, sim esse candidato existe, pois faço uma pesquisa no MySQL e ele está lá.

Comment: Já tentou com outro valor? Faça um teste assim: `$query_rsRegistro = "SELECT \`nome\`, \`email\`, \`celular\`, \`id_municipio\`, \`id_uf\`, \`dt_nascimento\` FROM \`candidato\` WHERE id_candidato = '158'";`

Comment: Olá @user3043340, sim foi um dos primeiros testes que fiz, também não é isso.

Comment: Amigo, seu código aparenta estar correto, porém acho que ele não está exibindo nenhum registro porque não tem nenhum registro, acho que sua Query retorna zero, faça um teste, procure verificar se a variável: $totalRows_rsRegistro possui algum valor antes de fazer a listagem na tabela, outra coisa, tente executar sua Query dentro do Banco de dados para ver qual o retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refiz minha consulta montando e exibindo a tabela de uma modo diferente, pois não consegui resolver o problema de exibição dos dados da anterior.

```
// Consultando candidados no banco
foreach($checkboxes as $id) {

    mysql_select_db($database_con, $con);
    $query_rsRegistro = "SELECT nome, email, celular, id_municipio, id_uf, dt_nascimento FROM candidato WHERE id_candidato = '$id'";
    $rsRegistro = mysql_query($query_rsRegistro, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro);
    $totalRows_rsRegistro = mysql_num_rows($rsRegistro);

    $Nome = $row_rsRegistro['nome'];
    $Email = $row_rsRegistro['email'];
    $Celular = $row_rsRegistro['celular'];
    $Municipio = $row_rsRegistro['id_municipio'];
    $UF = $row_rsRegistro['id_uf'];
    $Nascimento = $row_rsRegistro['dt_nascimento'];

    $tabela = "     
     <table width=100%  border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1>
      <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>E-mail</td>
        <td>Celular</td>
        <td>Municipio</td>
        <td>UF</td>
        <td>Nascimento</td>
      </tr>";            
    do {            
      $tabela .= "
      <tr>
        <td>{$Nome}; </td>
        <td>{$Email}; </td>
        <td>{$Celular}; </td>
        <td>{$Municipio};</td>
        <td>{$UF};</td>
        <td>{$Nascimento};</td>     
      </tr>";
    } while ($row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro)); 
    $tabela .= "</table>";  

}
```

Comment: Você pode fornecer mais informação para sua pergunta através do link de editar

Comment: Neste caso, o autor da questão não está adicionando mais informações à pergunta, mas está publicando a solução a qual ele chegou. Portanto, no meu entendimento, esta não deixa de ser uma resposta válida.